# uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Orm - Rails 4 (ckeditor gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hey guys i am trying to install ckeditor gem on my environment but i can't upload files or pictures i get this

```
NameError in Ckeditor::PicturesController#index

uninitialized constant Ckeditor::Orm

extracted source:

class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase

  delegate :url, :current_path, :content_type, :to => :data

  validates_presence_of :data
```

i am using carrierwave + minimagick and i did use the command to install and did migration as well.

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

He is not using Paperclip so correct answer would be

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase
  include Ckeditor::Backend::CarrierWave
end
```

http://www.maxmakedesign.co.uk/development/2014/rails-ckeditor-uninitialized-constant/

Answer (score 1):

i was getting the same error until i added this to the file

```
config/initializers/ckeditor.rb: 

 require "ckeditor/orm/active_record"
```

and restart rails server

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue before with Rails 4, but I fixed this issue by adding following code to app/models/ckeditor/asset.rb

```
class Ckeditor::Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveRecord
  include Ckeditor::Orm::ActiveRecord::AssetBase
  include Ckeditor::Backend::Paperclip
end
```

Here is the blog post I followed http://www.maxmakedesign.co.uk/development/2014/rails-ckeditor-uninitialized-constant/